# 301 redirection in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am creating htaccess for my site I need to redirect old urls to new url through 301 redirect. I have created code in htaccess as follows

My old urls like

```
 www.example.com/categories/city/cityname/brandname/product1.html
```

and my new url is like

```
 www.example.com/product1.html
```

For this scenario I have written following code in htaccess

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/categories/city/cityname/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

Please help me regarding this scenario or where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mod_rewrite's functionality in your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/categories/city/cityname/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @Seybsen answer, this 1 line should fit all your needs :

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$ /$5 [R=301,L]
```